# How To Get Homies Or Followers On Saints Row 4?

Tags: saints-row-iv

I have been played saints row about 1 week but I can't get homies or followers I have finished escape zin ship quest and I can costumize gangs but I can't get them as follower and how to get them?I meet followers in main quest?

Answer (score 1):

Call them on your Cellphone /

- Go to Upgrades
- Go Gang Abilities
- Buy the Call Saints Upgrade
- Click the < button on Xbox 360 button to Access phone
- Call Saints Backup
- There you go Enjoy :)

Answer (score -1):

There are a few requirements you must complete before you can start to recruit homies:

> After the ability to have Homies is unlocked, circles are shown in the top right corner of the HUD, to the left of the Health/Weapon section.

It kind of looks like so: [image]

> In the Saints Row, the Unlockable Natural Leader allows the player to recruit Homies; it is unlocked three times throughout the game and allows the player to recruit one more maximum Homie at a time each time it is unlocked, up to three maximum Homies at a time.

In order to unlock the ability, you have to complete the mission "[Canonized](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Canonized)". In addition, you will be able to do so another 2 times, after claiming 25% and 50% of [Stilwater's Neighborhoods](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Stilwater).

On the other hand, some homies come with missions.

> During some missions and activities, a character may be assigned to help The Protagonist, or to be protected. Normal Follower rules apply, and they can be revived if they lose all Health.

However, there are downsides. For example,

> During a mission, if the timer runs out for reviving a mission
>   critical Homie, the mission fails.

It is also not possible to use homies as [human shields](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Human_Shield).

There are also some special unlockable homies:

> Special Homies are Homies that are unlocked and added to the Cellphone throughout the game. These homies can only be recruited via the "Homies" menu of the cellphone. When they're called, they spawn in their own vehicle and drive to the player, and are automatically recruited when they exit their vehicle. They have more health than regular homies and take a longer time to faint.

However, be careful when you are using them as:

> attacking them mid-battle gives the message "(homie) has been dismissed!" After a homie has died or been dismissed, they cannot be called again for a certain period of time. It is only possible to call the number of Homies that can be recruited - up to 3 once all follower slots have been unlocked.

If you want to know the different types of homies and what you need to do to get or recruit them, go to the [Saints Row 4 Wiki](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Homies#Homies).

Reference: [LINK](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Homies)

Comment: This answer is pretty much useless, It's talking about __Saints Row 1__. There are even mentions to Stilwater. OP was asking for __Saints Row 4__. C'mon...